# C# and ExcelLibrary How to Right Align cells

Tags: c#, excel, excellibrary

Does anybody know how to make it so that the content passed to the sheet will right align?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to align one cell use

```
worksheet.Cells[y, x].HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;
```

If you want to align more than one

```
worksheet.get_Range("A1", "A30").Style.HorizontalAlignment = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignRight;
```

If you can not use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel then I am not really sure but you can try to use ExcelCellStyle

```
ExcelCellStyle titleStyle = workbook.Styles.AddStyle("WorksheetTitleStyle");
// align the text
titleStyle.Alignment.HorizontalAlignment = ExcelCellHorizontalAlignmentType.right;
titleStyle.Alignment.VerticalAlignment = ExcelCellVerticalAlignmentType.Center;
```

you might find more here:
http://www.winnovative-software.com/ExcelLibDemo/RangesAndCells.aspx

Comment: Is this with the ExcelLibrary.Spreadsheet or with Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel? The machine this is running on doesn't have excel installed on it so i cant use Interop

Comment: If you can not use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel then I am not 100% on this but you might be able to use what I added about the ExcelCellStyle.  also change workbook to whatever you named your instance of workbook. Hope this helps

Comment: It doesn't have that property, but thank you for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;

 using (ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook wb = new ClosedXML.Excel.XLWorkbook())
  {
    var ws = wb.Worksheets.Add("WorkSheetName");
    ws.Range(firstCellRow, firstCellColumn, lastCellRow, lastCellColumn).Style.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Right;
  }
```

if you want to right allign specific portion in worksheet